# Can selenium-side-runner run XML export from Katalon Recorder?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, katalon-recorder

Can selenium-side-runner run the XML export from Katalon Recorder? The Selenium-IDE plugin generates JSON output for .side files.